# Create a new table from given array with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

In a MySQL stored procedure how could I create a new table with the values of the "array":
`[5,3,4,2]` 
I would use this table for another purpose and then delete it at the end of the procedure, but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: I mean you should to use temporary table within your stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSON:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(a JSON)
BEGIN
  -- CREATE TABLE tab AS
  SELECT *  
  FROM JSON_TABLE(a ,"$[*]" COLUMNS(i INT PATH "$")) s;
END
```

Call:

```
CALL my_proc('[5,3,4,2]');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f049d6f59a82ae164ac4372897424a74)**